# Puppet agent on Windows - Warning messages in Windows Application Logs

Tags: puppet

I have puppet master 3.6.2 on Linux and puppet agent 3.6.2 on Windows Server 2008 R2

On the Windows servers in Windows Application Logs I have Warning messages:

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Puppet
Date:          9/26/2014 11:19:59 AM
Event ID:      2
Task Category: None
Level:         Warning
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      -
Description:
Copying owner/mode/group from the source file on Windows is deprecated; use source_permissions => ignore.
(at C:/Program Files (x86)/Puppet Labs/Puppet/puppet/lib/puppet/type/file/source.rb:120:in `each')
```

I have found many some warning messages in logs in other topics about puppet and windows. But nobody tells or asks about them.

Comment: Can you show us the manifest or an example manifest causing this issue? I'm using an older version of puppet (3.4.3) but I think you need to specify the file permissions in the file resource. I would expect that would stop that error.

Comment: Hi, this error is the first message when I start puppet agent on windows server. It's independent from my manifests.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely due to pluginsync, we fixed this in 3.7.0 - https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-2907

Note: The only way to fix this warning is to upgrade to at least 3.7.0.

Comment: Hi, thank you for reply.
I upgraded agents to 3.7.1 (x64).
But I have some warnings again:

Running Puppet agent on demand ...
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Loading facts
Info: Caching catalog for srv-smc.loyalty-partners.ru
Info: Applying configuration version '1411990452'
Warning: Copying owner/mode/group from the source file on Windows is deprecated;
 use source_permissions => ignore.
   (at C:/Program Files/Puppet Labs/Puppet/puppet/lib/puppet/type/file/source.rb
:133:in `block in copy_source_values')
Notice: Finished catalog run in 1.41 seconds